# jQuery - UI breaks once increase browser zoom level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a portal. Sizes are in %. Once i increase/decrease zoom level of browser (command + / command -) Ui breaks...

[image: When zoom level of browser is set to 100%]

[image: Zoom level is 175%]

Comment: This seems like a CSS issue rather then JavaScript. Are you setting these percentages with jQuery?

Comment: I have added flag 'CSS3'...

Comment: I am setting sizes dynamically using javascript that is why sizes changes according to window.innerWidth......

Comment: I think it would be best if you used a grid and didn't set element sizes with JS - ex.: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your design responsive to avoid this kind of issues.
Use these links to know more :

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Here header should be sticky that is why i have used position as fixed for header part and for some other div's which n all were needed to be sticky....But due to that i am facing lots of issues while increasing or decreasing % resolution (zoom in- zoom out)